# Can you control individual properties in firebase realtime database security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need to control access to individual properties under a user object in the users directory in the firebase rtdb. My current rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "name": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "plans": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "survey": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "survey_done": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID' || $uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "notes": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID'",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID'"
        },
        "status": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID'",
            ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID'"
        }
      }
    },
    "sending": {
      ".write": "auth.uid === 'adminID'",
      ".read": "auth.uid === 'adminID'"
    }
  }
}
```

The admin should be able to access all the data, but when I login as him on my web app, I get a permission_denied error.

Also, the user (not admin) should be able to see their `name, plans, survey and survey_done` properties but none of the others that are admin protected. When a user makes a read request to `users/their-user-id` I get the same error as above. Ideally it would just return all the properties the user does have access to, but the only way the user can access these are to read request to them individually.

The query I am using is:
`firebase.database().ref("users").child(id).once("value")`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query for the contents of a specific node in the database, security rules with either allow access to the **entire** contents of that node and all of its children, or reject all access.  You can't use security rules to filter some of the children from view.

Typically what people do is split the node into two children, and protect each child separated, based on the roles required of the user.  So, in your case, there would be one node that contains name, plans, survey, and survey_done.  Then there would be another node for notes and status.  Each container node would have different permissions.